# How to make a curve smoothing in matlab?

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, curve-fitting

[image: Gradient Image]

the blue plot is a noisy plot of the original plot(red). Is there any way to approximate the blue plot to nearly red plot?

Comment: Sure. There are many many different ways of achieving this, what have you tried? As a simple first approach, give a moving average filter a shot, or, since you seem to have large outliers, a moving median filter. Uploading a sample of your data would make sense.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Let's define a wavy function:

```
x = 0:.1:20;
y1 = 5*sin(x) + 2*x - x.^2 +.3*x.^3 - .2*(x-15).^4 - 10*x.^2.*cos(x./3+12).^3 + .5*(x-12).^4;
```

And add lots of noise:

```
r = randi(1000,1,201) - 500;
y2 = y1+r;
```

Now make a 1D Gaussian filter, normalize it and [convolve](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/conv.html) it with our function:

```
g = gausswin(20); % <-- this value determines the width of the smoothing window
g = g/sum(g);
y3 = conv(y2, g, 'same')
```

Let's see the result

```
figure;
hold on; 
plot(y1, 'r', 'linewidth', 3); 
plot(y2, 'b'); 
plot(y3, 'g', 'linewidth', 3);
```

Red the original function, blue the noisy version, green the smoothed, 'recovered' function.

[image: line graph of smoothed function]

Comment: First of all, this is not a polynomial. Secondly, the example noise in the plot in the original question is not at all normally distributed, and certainly not homoscedastic. A Gaussian filter involves some implicit assumptions.

Comment: Firstly, fair enough, it's a polynomial plus a sine. Secondly, I think it still works. But sure, another filter might give better results for his data, I'm not saying this is the only way to do it.

Comment: @Junuxx yes it kind of worked when I did an averaging filter on the results of gaussian filtering. and yes its true that the noise is normally distributed so the result is not good enough.

Comment: Note: For `gausswin()`, the Signal Processing Toolbox is required.

Comment: @Junuxx this was very useful for me, thanks! Where can I get more info about this topic (data filtering, gaussian window... etc)? any resource/good book that you recommend?

Answer (score 11):

another option is to use 'smooth'. I like to use it because it is a **single line** function.  Using the code of the previous answer by @Junuxx:

```
x = 0:.1:20;
y1 = 5*sin(x) + 2*x - x.^2 +.3*x.^3 - .2*(x-15).^4 - 10*x.^2.*cos(x./3+12).^3 + .5*(x-12).^4;
r = randi(1000,1,201) - 500;
y2 = y1+r;
```

Now apply smooth:

```
ys = smooth(x,y2,0.25,'rloess');
plot(x,y2,x,ys)
```

[image]

For more info:

```
doc smooth
```

Comment: *To use 'smooth', you might need:   smooth - Curve Fitting Toolbox*

Answer (score 4):

`gausswin()` requires the *Signal Processing Toolbox*

`smooth()` requires the *Curve Fitting Toolbox*

If you don't have these toolboxes, here is a simple `smooth()` implementation:

**smooth.m:**

```
function yy = smooth(y, span)
    yy = y;
    l = length(y);

    for i = 1 : l
        if i < span
            d = i;
        else
            d = span;
        end

        w = d - 1;
        p2 = floor(w / 2);

        if i > (l - p2)
           p2 = l - i; 
        end

        p1 = w - p2;

        yy(i) = sum(y(i - p1 : i + p2)) / d;
    end
end
```

**result for `y3 = smooth(y2, 15)`, using @Junuxx code:**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just to add an additional option :

Use `cftool` in the prompt of matlab:

- [What is cftool in matlab](http://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/cftool.html)
- [How to use cftool an example](http://www.swarthmore.edu/NatSci/echeeve1/Ref/MatlabCurveFit/MatlabCftool.html)

[image]